# jQuery re-bind .submit() after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, submit, bind

I'm creating a forum-style system where posts are created and users can then post comments on the original post. (What I'm doing is actually very different in context but the theme is the same).

The form to add a comment is part of the Post, which is pulled in using jQuery $.get().

Here's the submit handler currently:

```
$('#add-stage-form').submit(function(){

        var data = $('#add-stage-form').serialize();
        add_stage(data);
        return false;   
    });
```

Okay.. now, I need that to be re-bound once it's pulled in, in the same was `live()` can be used.

And please, if anybody suggests `live('submit', function(){ ...  })` I **WILL** scream because submit doesn't work like click!

I am also well aware that you I could bind the 'click' event on the same button - I'd **much** rather bind the .submit() event though, if possible

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: So you're reinjecting the button into the DOM after the submit?

Comment: Yes. I pull in [using .get()] a load of Posts, each with a comment box and submit button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the binding manually in the onComplete callback of the get method...

```
$.get('getposts.html', function(data) {
    var myForm = $(data);
    $('.formContainer').append(myForm);

    $('.add-stage-form', myForm).submit(function(){

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        add_stage(data);
        return false;   
    });

});
```

*edit
Changed add-stage-form to be a class rather than an id. You mentioned there will be a form per post?

Comment: You're right.. actually that might throw the whole thing off by making it impossible to serialize the correct (of potentially many) form without using ugly .find() functions.

Comment: You should be ok. You can use $(this) to get the form being submitted.

Updated answer

Comment: I'm halfway there - thank you! Will mark as 'correct answer' as soon as It's fully working! :)

Comment: Bang on mate, you're a star *

Comment: Cool, If you have any other issues let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Live()`? :)

But seriously, it might not be such a bad idea if you attach a click event to the button which then calls a `jQuery.Post()` opperation.  Or even a javascript method that submits the page.

I know this is not the (best) solution but it might get you over the line.

I'll retract this answer if a better one comes along.

Comment: No, you're right - I probably should just do that, I'd **love** to find a way to bind .submit though, it'd be really useful - especially if I want to use jQuery validate etc.. Comedy appreciated ;) (I almost went mental before reading on..)

Comment: I was in the process of testing this on jsfiddle and couldn't get it to work. Then jsfiddle flipped out and my test code was gone *sigh*

Comment: I fully endorse going mental now and again.  I actually quite like the idea of just having a button and then doing the submit in code.  I think then I can actually do some things, validation, before submitting.

Comment: @Alex coady, have you tries @Dean North's answer?

Comment: I have yeah, it's still not bound (clicking submit refreshes the page so the `return false` definitely isn't active.. )

Comment: RIGHT - It returns false now (via @Dean North's answer.) I'll post the final (working) solution once it's complete.